# Run "show slave status" with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, master-slave

I am trying to get the slave status of my MySQL server using PHP's PDO implementation. Running `fetchAll()` returns an empty array.

```
// DB IP, name, username, and password are fake here. I can connect.
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.0;dbname=production', 'username', 'password');
$result = $db->query("SHOW SLAVE STATUS");
$result->execute();

if ($result != false)
{
    $slave = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I have also tried removing the `->execute()` call, but it's the same result. Is there something completely obvious that I'm missing here? I've looked up and down the PDO::query documentation and it's not helping much.

Comment: Is your server's IP really `192.168.0.0`?  Although, I guess you would have seen an exception when connecting if this is where the problem was.

Comment: My bad, the IP and dbname are dummy content. Edited the OP.

Comment: No problem, was just checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have permission to execute the query?

Try:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.0;dbname=production', 'username', 'password');

$result = $db->query("SHOW STATUS");

if (!$result) {
    echo $db->errorInfo()[2]; // php 5.4
} else {
    foreach($result->fetchAll() as $row) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem. My replication user was not setup properly. I'll accept your answer once the 3 minute limit thing is gone. Cheers!

Comment: Ah I see you found it out about the same time I did, I tested it on my system and got the error about insufficient privileges so was figuring we had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually due to a permission's issue on the server. I incorrectly setup my replication user so replication itself wasn't even working.